# Rails generate scaffold error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

i'm having trouble generating scaffolding in my rails app:rails generate scaffold User name: string email:string

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static Referenced from: /Users/macowner/workspace/toy_app/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static Referenced from: /Users/macowner/workspace/toy_app/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle Expected in: flat namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your gems doesn't match your installed Ruby version.

Open up your Terminal utility, `cd /Users/macowner/workspace/toy_app` and run:

```
gem pristine --all
bundle install
```

This command will restore your gems to their original condition at the time you installed them.

Comment: @RogerHoffman If you would, please go ahead and click the checkbox next to this answer so people will know what worked.

Comment: Would there be a permanent solution to this? I have to issue this command everytime I open terminal.

Comment: That solution *should* be permanent. Are you using Homebrew, RVM or Rbenv to manage your Ruby libraries? Did you run `bundle install` after `gem pristine --all`?

Comment: I did that time run bundle install.

Comment: and no i wasn't runniing rvm. I switched to rvm and did bundle install

Comment: @RogerHoffman I've updated the answer to include the missing step. You can go ahead and click the checkbox to the left of the answer to let people know what worked for you.